# What language or tool does Google use in plotting graph on its web search?

Tags: clojure, incanter

Here is the result when I search `log x graph` in Google:

https://www.google.com/search?q=log+x+graph&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#newwindow=1&q=log+x+graph

The nice thing is that when I hover the mouse over the graph, it displays the values of (x,y).

1. What language or tool does it use?
2. How to draw this iterative graph in Clojure/Incanter?

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint

1. I bet it's https://developers.google.com/chart/
2. If you wanna display it within a browser you probably might use clojurescript
   https://github.com/dribnet/strokes rather than incanter

Sorry for the brevity